# create a component for joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla

I am new to joomla.
i create a component according to this [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Absolute_Basics_of_How_a_Component_Functions) from docs.joomla .this component install sucessfully on joomla 3. I go to this component by add this section in end of my url of my site.

```
index.php?option=com_testup
```

but I receive a 404 error.
this is my file structure

```
com_testup.php
com_testup.xml
controller.php
```

I create a zip from file above and set com_testup for name of this zip file.
the content of my com_testup.php is :

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT .'/controller.php');
// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by <name>
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('testup');

// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
?>
```

the content of my controller.php is:

```
<?php
defined ('_JEXT') or die ('Restericted access');
jimport ('joomla.application.component.controller');
class testupControler extents JcontrolerLagecy 
{
function display()
  {
    echo 'displaying';
  }
}
?>
```

the content of my com_content.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="3.1.0">
 <name>testup</name>
 <version>1.01</version>
 <description>test upload</description>

 <filename>com_testup.xml</filename>
 <filename>com_testup.php</filename>
  <filename>controller.php</filename>

 <administration>
  <menu>testup</menu>
 </administration>
</extension>
```

but i can not access this component from back-end and from frond-end .under the component menu in joomla administrator i see the "testup" menu .but when I click on it appeare the

```
404 Component not found
```

for me.
please help me.

Comment: you dont think that the name of name of com_tesup.php should be testup.php. and try using xdebug in netbeans or ecllipse to findout where your code is causing problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. You get a `404` because you haven't really made a component. That's because the article you referenced is about how components function, and it's a very light weight description, that's why it's called "[**Absolute Basics** of How a Component Functions](http://docs.joomla.org/Absolute_Basics_of_How_a_Component_Functions)".
2. The `404` and the misleading message is generated when Joomla tries to `render` the component. In 2.5 if you set **Debug System** to `Yes` and set the **Error Reporting** to `Development` you would see the `call stack` as well as the message and it would look something like this:

e.g.

```
Call stack
# Function  Location
1 JAdministrator->dispatch() /jdev/administrator/index.php:46
2 JComponentHelper::renderComponent() /jdev/administrator/includes/application.php:153
3 JError::raiseError() /jdev/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:337
4 JError::raise()   /jdev/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
```

To make a full component you need `Views` and lots of other bits, for each section of Joomla (it's actually two applications one for **/administrator** and the other for the frontend).

Joomla has it's own [MVC](http://docs.joomla.org/Model-View-Controller) that you'll need to learn, to start off work through the "[Developing a MVC Component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/3.1/Introduction)" introduction.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made a view. Not all components need views and not all views need to be html (they can be xml or json for example), but if you want to browse to a page and have it render you need to be creating an html document (look at the core extensions that all have view.html.php).